# Azure Databrick dbfs file uploaded and folder created not listing in notebook and vice versa

Tags: azure-databricks

I have created multiple folders in location dbfs:/FileStore/demo_store using Browse DBFS.

These folders are not listed when accessing from notebook using %ls.

Dont think,its due to syntax.Nop.

I was working with folder and uploaded file in morning.Now when i created new folder its not working. And also the folders created by notebook using mkdir command listed in notebook but not displayed in explorer/browse.

dbfs:/FileStore/demo_store/built_model/trained_vggface.h5

In code(notebook) i am using :
This not works - %ls /FileStore/demo_store/trained_models/

This works. - %ls /FileStore/demo_store/

the folder created in morning and files uploaded in morning are still accessible from notebook.But now when i upload in explorer its not showing in notebook, and saved in notebook not shown in explorer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II7eb.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhuVm.png)

I checked all user and admin settings.no issues.
The same features were working in morning, or the morning code blocks still works.and no issues.
New folders created and file uploaded not listing in notebook.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out an answer for this. But there is some serious bugs in Azure Databricks, I think.

I will share two pieces of code, both are working in Databrick. The funny thing is that the first method still works, but when using that in upcoming cells or notebooks it's not working. Azure must check the issue.

I got solution from https://kb.databricks.com/dbfs/how-to-specify-dbfs-path `/dbfs/mnt/test_folder/test_folder1/`; I have reformatted this for my needs.

#Code 2
The important line in this context is:

```
OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/dbfs/FileStore/output/images/"
```

```
# initialization
image_height = 48
image_width = 48
window_size = 24
window_step = 6
SAVE_IMAGES = True
SELECTED_LABELS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
IMAGES_PER_LABEL = 500
OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/dbfs/FileStore/output/images/"

def data_download():
    print( "preparing")
    try:
        os.makedirs(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME):
            pass
        else:
            raise
            
    
    print( "importing csv file")
    
    # Load the dataset
    data_set_path = "/FileStore/input/dataset/fer2013.csv"
    data = spark.read.csv(data_set_path,header=True,inferSchema=True)
    # display(data)
    data = data.toPandas()

    # data = pd.read_csv('../datasets/raw/fer2013.csv') # data from kaggle stored here as csv file.
    print(data.head(2))

    for category in data['Usage'].unique():
        # print(category)
        # time.sleep(3)
        print( "converting set: " + category + "...")
        # create folder
        if not os.path.exists(category):
            try:
                os.makedirs(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME):
                   pass
                else:
                    raise
        
        # get samples and labels of the actual category
        category_data = data[data['Usage'] == category]
        samples = category_data['pixels'].values
        labels = category_data['emotion'].values
        
        # print("\ncategory:",category_data,"\nsamples:",samples[0],"\nlabels:",labels)
        # time.sleep(3)
        # get images and extract features
        images = []
   
        print("Length of samples,labels\n:::::")
        print(len(samples),len(labels))
        print("\nSelected labels:",SELECTED_LABELS)
        # print(type(labels),type(samples))
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(len(samples)):
            # print("inside for loop:",i)
            try:
                if labels[i] in SELECTED_LABELS: 
                    if i%1000 == 0:
                        print(i,"inside if class:")
                    # image = np.fromstring(samples[i], dtype=int, sep=" ").reshape((image_height, image_width))
                    image = np.fromstring(samples[i], dtype=np.uint8, sep=" ").reshape((image_height, image_width))
                    images.append(image)
                    # print(image)
                    imageio.imwrite(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg', image)
                    # break
                    
            except Exception as e:
                print( "error in image: " + str(i) + " - " + str(e))
                break
        print("image count",len(images))        
        np.save(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category + '/images.npy', images)

#Code 1 :still work ,but not able to reproduce in another notebook or cell:
line of importance is : OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/FileStore/demo_store"


# initialization
image_height = 48
image_width = 48
window_size = 24
window_step = 6
SAVE_IMAGES = True
SELECTED_LABELS = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
IMAGES_PER_LABEL = 500
OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/FileStore/demo_store"

def data_download():
    print( "preparing")
    try:
        os.makedirs(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME)
    except OSError as e:
        if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME):
            pass
        else:
            raise
            
    
    print( "importing csv file")
    
    # Load the dataset
    data_set_path = "/FileStore/demo_data/fer2013.csv"
    data = spark.read.csv(data_set_path,header=True,inferSchema=True)
    # display(data)
    data = data.toPandas()

    # data = pd.read_csv('../datasets/raw/fer2013.csv') # data from kaggle stored here as csv file.
    print(data.head(2))

    for category in data['Usage'].unique():
        # print(category)
        # time.sleep(3)
        print( "converting set: " + category + "...")
        # create folder
        if not os.path.exists(category):
            try:
                os.makedirs(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category)
            except OSError as e:
                if e.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME):
                   pass
                else:
                    raise
        
        # get samples and labels of the actual category
        category_data = data[data['Usage'] == category]
        samples = category_data['pixels'].values
        labels = category_data['emotion'].values
        
        # print("\ncategory:",category_data,"\nsamples:",samples[0],"\nlabels:",labels)
        # time.sleep(3)
        # get images and extract features
        images = []
   
        print("Length of samples,labels\n:::::")
        print(len(samples),len(labels))
        print("\nSelected labels:",SELECTED_LABELS)
        # print(type(labels),type(samples))
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(len(samples)):
            # print("inside for loop:",i)
            try:
                if labels[i] in SELECTED_LABELS: 
                    if i%1000 == 0:
                        print(i,"inside if class:")
                    # image = np.fromstring(samples[i], dtype=int, sep=" ").reshape((image_height, image_width))
                    image = np.fromstring(samples[i], dtype=np.uint8, sep=" ").reshape((image_height, image_width))
                    images.append(image)
                    # print(image)
                    imageio.imwrite(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category + '/' + str(i) + '.jpg', image)
                    # break
                    
            except Exception as e:
                print( "error in image: " + str(i) + " - " + str(e))
                break
        print("image count",len(images))        
        np.save(OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + '/' + category + '/images.npy', images)
```

Conclusion:

- #Code 2 `OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/dbfs/FileStore/output/images/"`
- #Code 1 `OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME = "/FileStore/demo_store"`

I don't know why the second line does not works now.

And also to use in `%ls` command use `/dbfs/FileStore/`